# How do I use multiple xml "style sheets" in Android?

Tags: android, xml, stylesheet

I would like to use multiple xml style sheets in Android project.

I have:

```
res/
  values/
    styles.xml
    some_other_styles_file.xml
    and_some_other_styles_file.xml
    ...
```

What is the proper way to:

**1** - reference those files

**2** - reference individual styles from within different files

And:

**3** - if using multiple xml style sheets, do style names need to be unique across files? In other words could two files, each being used by the app, contain styles with the same name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File names are just for your organization, they are all *automatically* compiled and referenced by `R.style.<style_name>` when in *java*, or by `style = "@style/<style_name>"` when in *xml* (such as layout files). You can even mix types (e.g. have string resources in your styles.xml)

> To create a set of styles, save an XML file in the res/values/
>   directory of your project. The name of the XML file is arbitrary, but
>   it must use the .xml extension and be saved in the res/values/ folder.
>
> The root node of the XML file must be `<resources>`.

[source](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

1. You reference them all the same way `R.style.<style_name>`
2. It does not matter which file the styles are defined (files are used for organization)
3. Yes the names must be unique.

Comment: so apparently all xml files within the `res/values/`  directory are automatically included (compiled) into the .apk ???? ... (thus all styles in them would each be automatically available)

Comment: well, yes ... will all xml files within that directory automatically be compiled ... ... or do I need to add anything to the build file, or maybe the manifest file ??? .. thanks ...

Comment: Did you read the documentation linked? As it states (and is quoted) you create  `whatever.xml` in `res/values/` directory. No you do not need to add anything else.